# Black queens on $n\times n$ board

Tags: combinatorics

I conjecture that the maximum number of black queens -- queens placed on black squares -- not threatening each other that can be placed on an $n\times n$ chessboard cannot exceed $\frac{2n}{3}$. I have not programmed this question, but have a 'lower half triangle' proof for $n=8$ (reducible to one case) and it seems that there is a similar exhaustive proof for $n=12$ (involving $79$ cases). A better approach is needed for (dis)proving this conjecture, would first like to know whether this is a known result.

Note: if this conjecture holds, it implies at once that the ratio of the numbers $B, W$ of black and white queens on an n x n chessboard (with $B + W = n$) is between $1/2$ and $2$. (On a $8\times 8$ chessboard always $B = W = 4$, on a $12\times 12$ chessboard a 'knight placement' easily yields an example of $B = 8, W = 4$.)

Source: https://mathematica.gr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=183&t=71094

Answer (score 6):

Your conjecture is false. Consider $n=25$. You claim there can be at most $\frac{2n}{3}\approx 16.6667$ black queens. Here is a configuration with $17$ black queens.

Assuming the top left box is black:

[image]

Here is the [C++ code](https://ideone.com/4hYIQj) I used to find a counter example.

Comment: The first counterexample is at $n=10$: [Seven queens](https://pastebin.com/90Z4szD9)

Comment: @DanielMathias I am assuming the top left corner is black. Is there a counter example for $n<25$?

Comment: For even $n$, the board is symmetrical: One major diagonal is black. Just flip the solution in the link.

Comment: Counterexamples exist for all $n>9$. [Eight queens on 11x11](https://pastebin.com/H354Xvqh) (White diagonals, the solution can be shifted vertically for black diagonals.)

Comment: @DanielMathias Ahh I see the bug in my code. i assumed that you can put a queen on each line starting from the first. The first such example is n=25, but there are examples that skip lines that my code didn’t search. I’ll edit my answer

Comment: The maximum for $n=25$ turns out to be $19$:.

Comment: @DanielMathias The first counterexample is at $n=7$, with $5$ queens:
Q.......
...Q....
......Q.
.......
.......
.Q......
....Q...

Comment: @RobPratt I didn't search $n<8$ earlier, but $n=5$ with white corners allows for $4$ queens on black.

Comment: OK, I was assuming top left black like @AspiringMat but I guess the OP didn’t specify.